# How to rotate a rectangular img 90 deg at a pixel level in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to rotate an `<img>` element (JPG) 90 deg clockwise. The images might be rectangular and the <strike>solution must transform and rotate those pixel by pixel in Javascript (no CSS, no canvas transf, no jquery.rotate, etc)</strike> rotated image has to be saved to the server.

Comment: Not really sure exactly what you mean but you sure are picky with your requirements?!  What have you tried and why the restrictions?

Comment: `no CSS, no canvas transf, no jquery.rotate, etc` - won't work I guess.

Comment: Use the power of your brain and imagine it rotated 90 degrees. Otherwise use CSS.

Comment: I need to save the transformed/rotated img to the server. I've tried multiple JS libraries like pixastic, jquery.rotate, etc., but I cannot find a solution that let me save the transformed img to the server.

Comment: OK - servers are ideal for this kinda stuff, however what about transforming it on a canvas and then base64 encoding it somehow?

Comment: Agreed with Rob. You'll want to do this in canvas. You can then dump your canvas out as a base64-encoded string and, if you need binary image data, you can use something like `atob` or `btoa` go get it back to binary data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript.

Comment: Thanks guys, let me rephrase the question.